# Optional method arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, parameters, arguments

I have two methods that do almost the same thing, but but with a little difference in passing parameters:

```
def generate_file(filename)
  draw
  FileUtils.mkdir_p 'tmp/pdf'
  @pdf.render_file "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdf/#{filename}"
end

def generate_pdf(report, version)
  draw
  path = "tmp/pdf/reports/#{report.reference}"
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(path)
  @pdf.render_file "#{Rails.root}/#{path}/#{version}"
end
```

I want to refactor it, and use just the `generate_file` method when I call a function that generates pdf files. Should I pass an optional `params` (`version = nil`) and test if it's defined or not?

Like this:

```
def generate_file(filname, version = nil, report = nil) 
  draw
  if report && version
    path = "tmp/pdf/reports/#{report.reference}"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(path)
    @pdf.render_file "#{Rails.root}/#{path}/#{version}"
  else
    FileUtils.mkdir_p 'tmp/pdf'
    @pdf.render_file "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdf/#{filename}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Please use English punctuation, not the French one, when you write in English. Please be consistent with spacing within the code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some typos (`filname` instead of `filename`) and syntax errors (e.g., `if..end..else..end`) in the proposed code. How about something more like:

```
def generate_file(filename, version=nil, report=nil) 
  draw
  report_version = report && version
  path = report_version ? "tmp/pdf/reports/#{report.reference}" : "temp/pdf"
  FileUtils.mkdir_p( path )
  @pdf.render_file "#{ Rails.root }/#{path}/#{ report_version ? version : filename }"
end
```